# What happens when the actuator/heapdump endpoint is called in a Spring Boot application deployed to Cloud Foundry?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I have deployed my Spring Boot application to Cloud Foundry, and I have noticed that when I call the actuator/heapdump endpoint, there is a significant drop in memory usage. I am interested in understanding the specific actions that occur when this endpoint is invoked.

In my application, the actuator/heapdump endpoint seems to trigger a noticeable decrease in memory usage. I would like to gain insights into the underlying process and its impact on memory management. Can someone explain what exactly happens when the actuator/heapdump endpoint is called in a Spring Boot application deployed to Cloud Foundry?

Comment: A heap dump won't contain garbage. My guess is that by going through the heap while writing the dump garbage is identified. Therefore it can also be garbage collected during writing the dump.

Comment: I have allocated 8GB of Memory to my app and the app is consuming almost 95% of the memory but as soon as I hit the heap dump endpoint, memory consumption goes below 35%. I am curious, Why garbage is not collected beforehand.

Comment: There probably is garbage collected. But why collect more garbage than necessary? If the application can keep running with only collecting 100MB of garbage per run why waste cpu time on collecting more than that?

Comment: oh Understood, what if I decrease my heap size? will it lead to memoryOutofError? or garbage will be collected as soon as max heap size is reached?

Comment: It does lead error 137 in my experience. I'm exactly having this behaviour in my app on cf. I'm also wondering why memory usage drop that much when I trigger heapdump. If I don't, I get my app crashed because of `out of memory` after a while.